# Facebook Error: (#200) Subject does not have permission to post photos on this page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to post into a facebook page with image. I got this error `(#200) Subject does not have permission to post photos on this page`. Please help me. I don't know what to do.

```
FB.login(function(auth) {
  if (auth.status === 'connected') {
    FB.api('/me/accounts', 'get', function(response) {
      response.data.forEach(function(item) {
        if (item.id == "<page_id>") {
          post_to_page(item.access_token);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}, {scope: 'manage_pages, publish_pages, publish_actions'});

function post_to_page(access_token_data) {
    var data = {
      url: 'https://i.imgur.com/iXEkIJf.jpg'
    }

    FB.api('/<page_id>/photos', 'post', data, function(response) {
      if (!response || response.error) {
        console.log(response.error);
      } else {
        console.log(response.id);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: it seems to be that you try to post a link and not an image. Which value contains <page_id>?

Comment: Perhaps inside your `post_to_page` function you actually want to do something with the passed parameter, `access_token_data` ... right now you’re just ignoring it. Which means that right now, you are also not posting as the page, but as the user - and that is something page settings must explicitly allow. If they don’t ... you get this error message.

Answer (score 0):

I got it already and it works!

```
var FACEBOOK = {};
FACEBOOK.post_to_page = function() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      post_to_page(FB_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN);
    } else {
      FB.login(function(response) {
        post_to_page(FB_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN);
      }, {scope: 'manage_pages, publish_pages, publish_actions'});
    }
  });
}

function post_to_page(access_token_data) {
    var body = 'Facebook Error: (#200) Subject does not have permission to post photos on this page.';

    var data = {
      message: body,
      access_token: access_token_data,
      url: '<image_url>'
    }

    FB.api('/<fb_page_id>/photos', 'post', data, function(response) {
      if (!response || response.error) {
        console.log(response.error);
      } else {
        console.log(response.id);
      }
    });
}
```